# Get files back on a WinMagic protected HP Laptop

Tags: windows-10, crash, disk-encryption

I have a customer with an HP ProBook 430 G2. The device's hard drive has been encrypted by WinMagic / HP encryption software. The software seems to be part of the bootloader, and no part of the BIOS / UEFI.

This software encrypts the entire drive and asks for a password before the Windows Loader is being executed. No password, no data, no boot.

The problem: I know the password, and I can get past the WinMagic - screen. However, the OS itself (Windows 10) has become corrupt and keeps crashing on 0xc00000f at boot time. Loading up recovery is not possible.

With the encryption being part of the bootloader, and the OS being corrupt as hell, the data on the laptop is inaccessible. Does anyone know a way to disable encryption at boot time, or to recover data from another laptop using the password?

Comment: The only way to recover encrypted files is to decrypt them.  If the files can no longer be decrypted then the files cannot be recovered.  If WinMagic does not provide a way to decrypt them, because of a problem with the HDD (which is very likely given the details you provide) your customer is out of luck.  They should recover the data from their backups

Comment: @Ramhound it appears that you didn't quite understand the question, OP does indeed have the password/key to decrypt the data, but they need to be able to externally decrypt it because the Windows installation is corrupt.

Comment: @Yamakaja - It appears you didn't read my comment.  I never said the author didn't have the password, what I said was, the author has to have the ability to decrypt the files.  The author does not have that capability, and the reason likely is connected to a HDD failure, at this point it won't be possible to recover the files.

Comment: @Ramhound, I read your comment a couple times and came to the conclusion that you thought that he doesn't have the key: "If the files can no longer be decrypted then the files cannot be recovered."
But apparently I just missunderstood you.